How iOS devices setup MTU on cellular interfaces?
Could someone please advise on how iOS devices setup MTU on cellular (pdp_ip*) interfaces?
When iPhone is started in flight mode, all those interfaces have default MTU = 1500.
But after registering to LTE network, MTU on iPhone suddenly changes to 1450 - despite the fact that the LTE network is sending MTU=1500 in PCO during network attach.
This results in suboptimal (too low) MTU setting for upload direction, because this LTE network correctly delivers full 1500-byte user packets in the download direction (it uses larger MTU in the core to accomodate GTP and other overheads).
Seems 1450 is statically configured somewhere - does anyone know what parameter controls this?

Static assignment is possible, but I would expect something more like negotiation and discovery based on the cellular profile the carrier provides iOS or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery  is there a problem you’re facing here or just “I want to know how this works”

Added problem description to the original post. Negotiation via PCO is correctly performed, nevertheless all iOS devices always use MTU=1450 in this network.
